# Java Calender class showing incorrect date

Tags: java, datetime, time, calendar

I am trying to fetch the current date with Calender class. I am running my web application on tomcat. But I don't understand why it is displaying the month day as 36. Below is my code.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Output

```
Current Date Time : 2014/02/36 04:30:14
```

Can anyone please explain how can a day be 36?

Does the Calender class shows the system time or the tomcat server runs its own time?

Comment: By the way, if you are arbitrarily choosing to use slashes, consider using hyphens. Hyphens are common in that year-month-day order. That format is defined by the international [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `D` represents the *Day in year*. You need to use `dd` instead which represents *Day in month*. Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on different patterns and their representation.

Comment: @ShivangSarawagi Yes indeed you need to read the documentation linked in that answer. Your "YYYY" should be lowercase, and your "hh" should probably be uppercase.

Comment: @Basil: Thanks a lot for the advice, I really appreciate it. I made amends & it works absolutely fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the format you want is almost the standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If so, you should know that the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library that supplants the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar classes uses ISO 8601 format by default. So no need to define a formatter, Joda-Time already has one built-in.

The new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with Java 8 (and inspired by Joda-Time) also uses the ISO 8601 format by default.

Some example code using Joda-Time 2.3…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime_Paris = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 24, 10, 0, 0, timeZone );

// Convert to UTC/GMT.
DateTime dateTime_UTC = dateTime_Paris.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

System.out.println( "dateTime_Paris: " + dateTime_Paris );
System.out.println( "dateTime_UTC: " + dateTime_UTC );
```

When run…

```
dateTime_Paris: 2014-01-24T10:00:00.000+01:00
dateTime_UTC: 2014-01-24T09:00:00.000Z
```